# Flutter & Background fetch - How to handle a simple example?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am really wondering how to use the package https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch.

I want to run a simple task to grab entries from my sqllite DB to change status.

On the main.dart file, I have :

```
Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  initPlatformState();

  await DotEnv().load('.env');

  runApp(MyApp());

  // Register to receive BackgroundFetch events after app is terminated.
  // Requires {stopOnTerminate: false, enableHeadless: true}
  BackgroundFetch.registerHeadlessTask(backgroundFetchHeadlessTask);

  BackgroundFetch.start();
}
```

First, I am really not if I have to put : `BackgroundFetch.start();` ?

Then, here is my function called :

```
// Platform messages are asynchronous, so we initialize in an async method.
Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
  // Configure BackgroundFetch.
  BackgroundFetch.configure(BackgroundFetchConfig(
      minimumFetchInterval: 15,
      stopOnTerminate: false,
      enableHeadless: false,
      requiresBatteryNotLow: false,
      requiresCharging: false,
      requiresStorageNotLow: false,
      requiresDeviceIdle: false,
      requiredNetworkType: NetworkType.ANY
  ), (String taskId) async {
    // This is the fetch-event callback.
    print("[BackgroundFetch] Event received $taskId");

    // take all photos not uploaded
    final repo = di.get<DossierRepository>();
    final photosNotUploaded = await repo.getPhotosNotUploaded();

    await for (final photo in Stream.fromIterable(photosNotUploaded)) {
      // resend them simply
      repo.resendPhoto(photo.dossierId, photo.photoId);
    }

    // IMPORTANT:  You must signal completion of your task or the OS can punish your app
    // for taking too long in the background.
    BackgroundFetch.finish(taskId);
  }).then((int status) {
    print('[BackgroundFetch] configure success: $status');
  }).catchError((e) {
    print('[BackgroundFetch] configure ERROR: $e');
  });
}
```

I have this warning :

```
[TSBackgroundFetch start] Task flutter_background_fetch already registered
```

I understand I have to check if the task is not registered, but how ? And if I make changes to my code, I need to "destroy" the old task and register the new one ?

And is it the good way of using this plugin ? I have only 1 Task for my app, I want it to run all the time. Do I have to register Tasks ? Or this is enough ?

Answer (score 0):

flutter_background_fetch is the default taskid of BackgroundFetch, which will be auto-registered by BackgroundFetch when initPlatformState. It means that you should not use flutter_background_fetch as a taskid.